# Not able to read the value from Examples in the Background section for Karate

Tags: karate

For the **Karate** Framework with BDD, I am trying to pass value for some of the **Background** steps from the **Examples** section of the **Scenario Outline** but I have not been able to succeed. Any pointers?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3tzR.png)

**My Outcome** ---> if you observe the value is not getting replaced for the variable under the Background section and it simply prints ''. Where as the value for '' is correctly being replaced accordingly as the name provided in the Examples Section.
Additionally if I try to omit the single quote to make it simply  it then complains as if it is not a valid xml. So basically no matter what I have issue of the value not being passed under the Background step.

Comment: next time please read this before asking another question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Karate only performs `<foo>` kind of placeholder substitution in the `Scenario Outline` steps.

But the variable will be available even in the `Background`. In your example, `def greeting = param` will work. Refer to the documentation: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#scenario-outline-enhancements

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked and yes the above link has been very useful